# Get input field of this element

Tags: jquery, html

After a click on `.option-item`, I'll get the input tag type is hidden of the trigger *(in JavaScript `this`)*.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".option-item", function() {
    $("#resultaatArtisten").css("display", "none");
    alert(this.$('input[type="hidden"]').val());
});
```

```css
.option-list {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: solid 1px #A9A9A9;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.option-item {
 display: flex;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.option-item:hover {
 background-color: #1DD75F;
}

.artist-foto-container {
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-item">
    <input type="hidden" value="123"/>
    <div class="artist-foto-container">
        <img src="" style="" class="artist-foto" alt="Foto van "/>
    </div>
    <p>name</p>
</div>
```

But if gives me this error:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** `this.$` is not a function

Are there some ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
$(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val()
```

I see your thinking, but you must always ask what the contextual value of `this` is. In your case, `this` points to the clicked `div`, i.e. an HTML element object.

Knowing this, it's obvious the jQuery instance, `$`, does not live under - is not a sub-object of - that DIV.

Instead, to go beyond, i.e. delve within, that DIV, you pass it to jQuery (to expose it to the jQuery API) and then use the `find()` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("body").on("click", ".option-item", function() {
    $("#resultaatArtisten").css("display", "none");
    alert($(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
});
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is totally wrong. Change the below line:

```
alert(this.$('input[type="hidden"]').val());
```

To:

```
alert($(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
```